# Are there any stable (not metastable) string theory compactifications with a positive cosmological constant?

Tags: string-theory, cosmology

Previously, on https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86509/33806, I asked how we can be saved from false vacuum decay assuming we are living in a false vacuum.

What if we are living in a stable vacuum after all, and string theory actually describes the world we live in? Are there any stable (not metastable) string theory compactifications with a positive cosmological constant?